# else statement skipped when it shouldn't be

Tags: c, if-statement

So I have a weird problem that I can't wrap my head around. I have a if...else if...else block that doesn't execute the else statement when both the if and else if statements are false.

```
int load(void)
{
    int index = 0;

    // temp string buffer for characters.
    _TCHAR* str = calloc(sizeof(TCHAR), 127);


    // open config file.
    FILE* fp = fopen("config.txt", "r");
    // if file is NULL, return.
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open config.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    do
    {
        int c;
        // get characters from the file and put them in the message buffer.
        do
        {
            c = fgetc(fp);
            // if new line found end word.
            if(c == '\n')
            {
                str[index] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            // if EOF return.
            else if(c == EOF)
                return 0;

            // else keep storing characters.
            else
            {
                str[index] = c;
                index++;
            }
        }while(1);

        // time specifier is found.
        if((str[0] == 't' || 'd' || 'c') && (isdigit(str[1]) != 0))
        {
            // if spec. is 't' store the time of day.
            if(str[0] == 't')
            {
                if(StoreTime(str) != 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Time of day could not be stored.\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            // if spec. is 'd' store the date.
            else if(str[0] == 'd')
            {
                if(StoreDate(str) != 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Date could not be stored.\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            // else spec. is 'c'.
            else
            {
                if(StoreCount(&str[1]) != 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Countdown could not be stored.\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        // comment text or new line found.
        else if(str[0] == '*' || '\n')
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        // message found.
        else
        {
            if(StoreText(str) != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Text could not be stored.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }

            index = 0;
    }while(1);

fclose(fp);
return 0;

}
```

And i have some if statements inside those as well mostly as function return checks but that should not affect the outermost statements if I'm not totally dizzy right now. But this code still skips the else statement.

When i run it with GDB it gets the value that i want, that doesn't trigger the first if statement or the else if statement. And then it just skips right down to the "do stuff regardless" part. So i have no idea what's going on.

EDIT* added real code

Comment: Please show the actual code.  What you have here won't compile (there are no `while`s to go with the `do`s, and your problem is likely with `{}` or `;` placement).

Comment: The pseudo code that you are showing can't help to find the problem. Cook your real code down to a minimal example.

Comment: I added the real code. took a while to format it neatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a couple of places you attempt to test for multiple values like this:

```
if (str[0] == 't' || 'd' || 'c')
```

That code is legal but it doesn't do what you want. You need separate tests for each value like this:

```
if (str[0] == 't' || str[0] == 'd' || str[0] == 'c')
```

Comment: Oh, i thought that worked since that command always triggered if it found a t d or c character. I'll have to keep that in mind. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @user3785768: The expression `str[0] == 't' || 'd' || 'c'` is evaluated as `str[0] == 't'` __or__ `'d' is non-zero` __or__ `'c' is non-zero`. The last two sub-expressions were always `true` and the `if` branch was being taken no matter what the value in `str[0]`.